# How to fix the error "Subscript out of bounds"

Tags: r, polynomials

I have a question about fixing the error:

> "subscript out of bounds".

I am analyzing data of an eye-tracking experiment. You may find example data below:

```
Stimulus  Timebin   Language  Percentage on AOI 
1            11        L1         0.80
1            11        L2         0.60
1            12        L1         0.80
1            12        L2         0.50
1            13        L1         0.83
1            13        L2         0.50
...
10           37        L1         0.00
10           37        L2         0.50
10           38        L1         0.70
10           38        L2         0.50
10           39        L1         0.60
10           39        L2         0.70
10           40        L1         0.75
10           40        L2         0.89

...
```

I would like to do a Growth curve analysis with the `Language` and `Timebin` as independent variables and `percentage on Area of Interest (AOI)` as dependent variable. Besides, the `Stimulus` as random factor. I got 40 timebins for each stimulus and condition. In order to avoid the potential problem of collinearity, I want to create orthogonalized polynomials. The code below was used to create independent (orthogonal) polynomial time terms (linear, quadratic, and cubic).

```
Gaze_1_Poly <- poly((unique(Gaze_1$timebin)), 3)
Gaze_1[,paste("ot", 1:3, sep="")] <- Gaze_1_Poly[Gaze_1$timebin, 1:3]
```

I always get an error told me that there is a Out of Bounds Subscript.

> Error in Gaza_1_Poly[Gaze_1$timebin,  :
>         subscript out of bounds

So I checked the class of variables and I think it is of no problem:

```
   Stimulus     Timebin    Language  percentage on AOI        
"character"   "integer"    "factor"   "numeric"
```

I can not figure out the reason. Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: for reproducibility, can you share example data such as Gaze_1

Comment: Hello @Ben. Thanks for your comment! I edited my question and added example data. It is very kind of you if you can take a look at my question again. I really appreciate it!

Comment: the problem is Gaze_1_Poly[Gaze_1$timebin, 1:3] --- Gaze_1$timebin is a vector of numbers 11...40 in your example, but the rows generated by Gaze_1_Poly start with number 1 (and go up to 7 with the example data) for the 3 polynomials --- i can try to provide solution a bit later if i have time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comment above. Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

```
library(dplyr)

Gaze_1 %>%
  left_join(data.frame(Timebin = unique(.$Timebin), poly(unique(.$Timebin), degree = 3)),
            by = 'Timebin') %>%
  setNames(c("Stimulus", "Timebin", "Language", "Percentage on AOI", "ot1", "ot2", "ot3"))
```

Comment: Thanks Ben! It works perfectly. You are right. This data is a subset from a bigger one. I got 50 time bins. And this data is cut from that one, showing data from time bin 11 to 50. This could lead to the error. Thanks again for helping me! Best wishes